# Birthday Paradox Assignment with Menu (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm a computer programming student in my second semester. Passing functions by value/reference is still something I'm struggling with. The following code generates a random set of 23 birthdays and tests for a match successfully. The problem is calling this function 1000 times to test the percentage of birthday matches.

I've tried a few different approaches, passing an int from main() to this function by reference, so whenever a match is found it increments this by 1. The other method I tried is creating an int inside the function set to 0. If a match is found this int is changed to 1 and returned. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int SortedArray();

int main(){

    srand(time(0));

    int count = 0;
    const int Columns = 23;

    for(int h=1; h<1000; h++){
        SortedArray();
        if(SortedArray() == 1){
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << count;
}


int SortedArray(){

    int MatchCount;
    int RandomSet[24] = {0};
    const int Columns = 24;


    for (int i=1; i < Columns; i++){
        RandomSet[i] = (rand()%366);
            if (RandomSet[i] == 0){
                RandomSet[i] = RandomSet[i] + 1;
            }
    }

    for (int l=0; l < Columns; l++){
        for (int k=1; k < Columns; k++){
            for (int j=1; j < Columns; j++){
                int Temp = 0;
                if (RandomSet[j] > RandomSet[j+1]){
                    Temp = RandomSet[j];
                    RandomSet[j] = RandomSet[j+1];
                    RandomSet[j+1] = Temp;
                }                   
            }
        }

        if(RandomSet[l] == RandomSet[l+1]){
                MatchCount = 1;
        }

    }   

return MatchCount;
}
```

Comment: 1) every pass of the loop you call `SortedArray` twice, 2) 1st of January is twice as likely to appear as any other day, use `rand()%365+1`, 3) You don't need to sort the array every pass of the loop with counter `l` 4) You are reading and modifying memory lying beyond the last element of the array, use `Columns-1` in loops with counters `l` and `j`. 5) `j` should start from zero or you won't include the zeroth element of the array in the sorting, 6) Match count can only be 1, did you intend to increment it? There may be more...

Comment: I don't see any question mark anywhere, do you intend to ask a question?

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts that I believe indirectly will address your issue:

1. Not all random number generators are created equal, and they need to be initialized properly in any case.
2. You are declaring `MatchCount` without giving it an initial value, then possibly returning it without ever setting it to anything. That is undefined behavior.
3. Even if there is a match, and you set `MatchCount` to `1`, what happens if you get a second match? You set it to `1` again. So you aren't counting every match.
4. Counting starts at 0. `RandomSet[i] = (rand()%366)` and then adding `1` to it if it is equal to `0` means that your day `1` is twice as likely to happen and your distribution is no longer uniform. Mod by 365, and if you have to display the day you can add `1` to it before displaying it to get it to the desired domain.
5. There are STL functions for sorting, you don't have to write your own.

Comment: These are just some random comments.

Comment: @Puppy Random comments that cover the potential undefined behavior in the program as well as why this won't statistically return the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your suggestions! Ryan, 3.) was deliberate. In a set of birthdays, it is only looking for 1 match. So if there were 2 or more matches in a set of 24, it would still only be counted as 1.

Yea, this assignment has really been kicking my ass.. The third part of this assignment is taking this array and converting it to Month/Day and displaying it as shown.

Here are the program parameters given
[HomeWork #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpJfU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem interesting. As already pointed out above it is not really necessary to sort the array anyway.

Even more the number of days is limited to 365, so memory is not a limiting factor. So I used the `std::set` data structure to work out the counting for me. I'm a really lazy programmer!

Observe that a `std::set` can contain each key exactly once, so if there are no collisions, the size of the set equals the size the numbers you put into it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <set>

int countCollisions(){

    int MatchCount;
    const int Columns = 25;
    const int Days = 365;
    std::set<int> RandomSet;
    for (int i=0; i<Columns; i++) {
        RandomSet.insert(rand()%Days);
    }
    return Columns-RandomSet.size();
}

int main(){

    srand(time(0));

    int atLeastOne = 0;
    int totalNumber = 0;
    const int Columns = 23;

    for(int h=0; h<1000; h++){
        int value=countCollisions();
        totalNumber+=value;
        atLeastOne+=value>0?1:0;
    }
    std::cout << atLeastOne << " " << totalNumber << std::endl;
}
```

Maybe you'd like to play with this code a little bit. Try to change the number of `Columns` to 366. You should get 1000 collisions, by the pigeonhole principle.